# Where was the Chancellor's guard when the Jedi Masters confronted him?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious, revenge-of-the-sith

As can be seen in the following clip from the Revenge of the Sith, a group of Jedi Masters led by Mace Windu, waltz right into Chancellor Palpatine's office completely unchallenged. Then they

> proceed to attack the Chancellor and all except Mace Windu are swiftly defeated as the Chancellor is actually Darth Sidius.

What is not seen in the clip is the Chancellor's personal guard, which as *a head of state he must have had one*. This begs the question of **where were they at that moment?**

Later on we see that

> (now Emperor) Palpatine actually has a guard, who however are swiftly defeated by Yoda.

Comment: At that point in time he didn't really need a guard. Later when Yoda comes he's been attacked and so now has a guard.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot  As a head of state he must have had a guard.

Comment: Why must he have had one? Should he have had one? Probably. Did he need one? No.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot If you have specific proof/references/quotes demonstrating that the Chancellor of the Republic doesn't have a guard, please post it as an answer :)

Comment: @Loki Padme was a Queen and didn't have "guards" (other than her hand-maidens) until there was a specific threat against her. And the chancellor was of the same people as Padme.  While it's a different situation to be sure, I think it speaks to how such things were treated in the Republic and specifically by the Naboo.

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach Captain Panaka was Head of Security and captain of the Royal Guard of Naboo. This was well before Phantom Menace.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - you may think that Palpatine/Darth Sideous didn't need any guards.  But he has red imperial guards in Return of the Jedi, and when he comes to Naboo at the end of the Phantom Menace he has guards with uniforms somewhat similar to the red imperial guards.  Thus Palpatine should have had guards all the way from the Phantom Menace to Return of the Jedi, and Mace Windau must have interacted with them off screen when getting to Palpatine's office.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There were two guards outside of the office, in fact, but we just never saw them. Their meeting with the Jedi Masters is briefly described in the behind-the-scene section of [a Wookieepedia article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Duel_in_Palpatine%27s_office#Behind_the_scenes):

> According to the screenplay of Episode III, the Chancellor's Rodian
>   aide Dar Wac and two members of the Senate Guard originally had a
>   cameo appearance before the Jedi entered Palpatine's office, in which
>   they would have tried to stop the Jedi only to be Force pushed into
>   the walls by them. This was either dropped or never filmed.

And checking [Star Wars Episode III: Illustrated Screenplay](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III_Revenge_of_the_Sith:_Illustrated_Screenplay) proves the fan-written wiki right!

> **127 (98) INT. CORUSCANT–LOBBY TO CHANCELLOR'S OFFICE–EARLY EVENING**
>
> The FOUR JEDI enter the lobby, raising their arms, and send the
>   Chancellor's aide, DAR WAC, flying against the wall, along with TWO
>   REPUBLIC GUARDS. They storm into the Chancellor's office.

Comment: Do you have access to the novelization? I’m curious if that scene was also present in that.

Comment: @Thunderforge Where's Valorum when you need him! :)

Comment: @Loki He's still bitter about this Palpatine guy being the Supreme Chancellor instead of him.

Comment: @Thunderforge yeah, but at least he didn't get thrown down a bottomless pit by his apprentice.

Comment: I'm changing my name to ValorumsApprentice =)

Comment: @Jules I was sure that there would be a safety net. Why else would his office be right next to a pit leading to the reactor? If he rolled his office chair far enough, it would fall in!